# How do I make a textview fill the height of a linear layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Ok, I've been spending hours trying to solve this or even find a solution online and so far nothing has worked. How can I make the TextView "content_note" fill the available space in this LinearLayout?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#000000"
android:id="@+id/screen">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/size"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:alpha=".0" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/current"
    android:background="@drawable/wood_background"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recent_notes_list">

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/gen_note"
    android:id="@+id/current"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:alpha=".75"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="35sp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/previous_txt"
    android:id="@+id/previous"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:alpha=".5"
    android:layout_above="@+id/settings" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="35sp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/next_button"
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:alpha=".5"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/note_frame"
    android:layout_above="@+id/settings" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/anim_frame_right"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/next"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/previous"
    android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/previous"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/anim_right_note">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/title_right"
                android:text="TITLE"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center|center_horizontal"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/content_right"
                android:text="Content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/anim_right_foreground"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/anim_frame_left"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/next"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/previous"
    android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/previous"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/anim_left_note">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/title_left"
                android:text="TITLE"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center|center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/content_left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
                android:text="Content"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/anim_left_foreground"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/anim_frame_left"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/anim_frame_left"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/anim_frame_left"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/previous" />
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/note_frame"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/next"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/previous"
    android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/previous"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/note_view"
            android:baselineAligned="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="10"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="fill_vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/title_note"
                android:text="TITLE"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center|center_horizontal"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_weight="9" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/title_note_text"
                android:text="TITLE"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center|center_horizontal"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_weight="9" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/content_note"
                android:text="Content_note"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:alpha="1"
                android:layout_gravity="top|left|bottom|right"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="337dp"
                android:id="@+id/content_note_text"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:alpha="1"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/foreground"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/size"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:alpha=".65"
    android:layout_below="@+id/size"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/size"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/previous"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
    android:contentDescription="settings"
    android:padding="60dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    android:text="+ New Note"
    android:id="@+id/new_note"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/settings"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/size"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/delete"
    android:alpha=".65" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/delete"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/settings"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
    android:alpha=".65"
    android:contentDescription="@string/delete" />
```

Comment: Please clarify which textview you want to set as full width/height

Comment: The one whose ID is "Content_note"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution is to use android:fillViewport="true" on the ScrollView**

and change this LinearLayout android:id="@+id/note_view" child control height from **wrap_content to fill_parent**.